# Dynamic generating data-targets

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, bootstrap-modal

I am developing a project with Meteor and Bootstrap, and I need to dynamic populate a modal with a bunch of accordions; until there, OK.

The problem is that I generate the IDs for both `href` and `data-target` dynamically, and inside the modal the collapsing event don't trigger.

Is there any special exceptions for setting dynamic `href` and `data-triggers` that I may be forgetting?

html:

```
<template name="BaseModal">
<div class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-scroll" id="briefing-modal">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">Briefing Eletrônico</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body" style="overflow: scroll;">
              <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                {{#each userAmbientList}}
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                    <h4 class="panel-title">
                      <a role="button" name="{{id}}" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#{{id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="{{id}}">
                        {{name}} {{complement}}
                      </a>
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div id="{{id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                      {{id}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                {{/each}}
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't mind it, the dynamic ids where already set in another place.

So, always keep an track on where are you using this damn ids :P